# How to edit checkout fields in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, hook-woocommerce

I am trying to edit the front-end of my checkout page within WooCommerce.

At the moment this is the generated html code that is shown on the checkout page:

```
<div class="column">
    <h2 class="title">Billing Details</h2>
    <?php if ( $checkout->get_checkout_fields() ) : ?>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_before_customer_details' ); ?>

        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_billing' ); ?>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_after_customer_details' ); ?>

    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

How do I change this so that the output code is like this:

```
<div class="column">
    <h2 class="title">Billing Details</h2>
    <?php if ( $checkout->get_checkout_fields() ) : ?>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_before_customer_details' ); ?>

        <div class="field">
          <label class="label">First Name</label>
          <div class="control">
            <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="First Name">
          </div>
        </div>

        etc......

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_after_customer_details' ); ?>

    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

This is to make the front-end look a lot more appealing for the user as I have already got CSS styling used across the other site pages and to clear up all the unnecessary markup produced by WooCommerce.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Refer this article https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/

Answer (score 3):

To edit checkout fields in woocommerce you will use some **action and filter hooks** like describe on the official documentation:

[**Customizing checkout fields using actions and filters in Woocommerce**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/)

It will explain you how to make the desired changes, giving you many code examples.

You will find in StackOverFlow many related threads [**using this search**](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bwoocommerce%5D%20checkout%20fields).

---

> **Update** *(related to your comment)*

#### Make changes on the generated html field types:

All checkout fields are generated from the function [**`woocommerce_form_field()`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-woocommerce_form_field.html#2066-2278) and if you look to the source code you can use the composite filter hook [**`"woocommerce_form_field_{$args\[type\]}"`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-woocommerce_form_field.html#2271) where `$args[type]` is the targeted field type to be changed:

```
$field = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_form_field_' . $args['type'], $field, $key, $args, $value );
```

Here are some existing examples code threads using this hook:

- [How to rearrange/customize html in woocommerce checkout form fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39267627/how-to-rearrange-customize-html-in-woocommerce-checkout-form-fields/39300503#39300503)
- [WooCommerce Custom Fields - Multiselect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13684533/woocommerce-custom-fields-multiselect/13811111#13811111)
- [WooCommerce: Dynamic Custom Checkout Fields in admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38463683/woocommerce-dynamic-custom-checkout-fields-in-admin/38471873#38471873)

As this is for checkout, you will use the conditional tag `is_checkout()`.

Comment: I understand the WooCommerce docs but how do I put my control and field divs around the input? From what I can see I'm able to change the placeholder and remove fields but not add my own HTML?

Comment: @TomHartley I have update my answer with an addition related to your comment. With this you get the right track to make changes in a correct way.